# EitherT + State type mismatch

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm working on a small program using Scala Cats. I'm encountering lots of type errors when trying to use `EitherT` with `State` and for comprehensions. For instance:

```
import cats.data.{EitherT, State}
import cats.data.State.get

object Test {
  type IntState[T] = State[Int, T]
  type IntStateEither[T] = EitherT[IntState, String, T]

  val test: IntStateEither[Unit] = for {
    isValid <- EitherT.right(get.map((it: Int) => it % 2 == 0))
    _ <- if (!isValid) EitherT.leftT("invalid number") else EitherT.rightT(())  // *
  } yield ()
}
```

Which gives me:

```
(...) Test.scala:12: type mismatch;
 found   : cats.data.EitherT[[A(in value <local Id>)]A(in value <local Id>),_1,Unit] where type _1 <: String
 required: cats.data.EitherT[[A(in class IndexedStateT)]cats.data.IndexedStateT[cats.Eval,Int,Int,A(in class IndexedStateT)],String,Unit]
one error found
```

If I comment out the line marked (*) above, this code compiles. I think I'm following the instructions [on the Cats website](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html#from-a-or-b-to-eithertf-a-b) under "From `A` or `B` to `EitherT[F, A, B]`" correctly, but do I need to give more type hints? If yes, I'm not sure where I can add them.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

I'm using Cats 2.0.0 and Scala 2.13.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that the compiler is not able to infer the correct types for `EitherT.leftT` and `EitherT.rightT`.
You can fix those errors using explicit types like: `EitherT.rightT[IntState, String]`, or if you only need one `flatMap` call, it seems doing it explicitly does work:

```
val test: IntStateEither[Unit] =
  EitherT
    .right[String](State.get[Int].map(it => it % 2 == 0))
    .flatMap { isValid =>
      if (isValid) EitherT.rightT(())
      else EitherT.leftT("invalid number")
    }
```

---

*PS: It may be worth checking if [**bm4**](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) helps*.

Comment: That works! bm4 did not solve the issue directly, but I've added it to my build anyways, it seems useful.